# how to finish razor section?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

I have this in my view :

```
    <input id="@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)"  type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>
    <input id="(@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password))"  type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Its working but my result is 
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you want to put HTML as tags:

```
<input id="UserName"  type="text" placeholder="Username" value="@Model.UserName" autofocus required />
<input id="Password"  type="password" placeholder="Password" value="@Model.Password" required />
```

Or let Razor to do it for you:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName);
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password);
```

You are mixing it together. Your example starts with pure HTML, then it finds the Razor command which renders another input tags, inside the pure HTML one. Prefer Razor code when you need to return the model type.